# Pandas DataFrame: Operation based on leading row

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have this csv file which has large amount of data. I have taken the csv as a dataframe in python. I want to compare each row with its corresponding row and if the first row has value 1 and second row has value 100 , then the program should replace 100 to 50. If there are 2 columns containing 1 above 100 , then the value of 100 should be changed to 25 , if 3 columns are there above 100 containing 1 ,  then the value of 100 should be 12.5 and so on.This is the dataframe of the csv file:

```
  rule_id           51594   51668   51147   51182   51447
0   comparison1     1.0      1.0     NaN    NaN      NaN
1   last_comp      100.0    100.0    NaN    NaN      NaN
2   comparison1     NaN      NaN     1.0    NaN      1.0
3   comparison2     NaN      NaN     1.0    NaN      1.0
4   comparison3     NaN      NaN     1.0    NaN      100.0
5   comparison4     NaN      NaN    100.0   NaN      NaN
```

The result should look like this:

```
     rule_id        51594   51668   51147   51182   51447
0   comparison1     1.0      1.0     NaN    NaN      NaN
1   last_comp       50.0     50.0    NaN    NaN      NaN
2   comparison1     NaN      NaN     1.0    NaN      1.0
3   comparison2     NaN      NaN     1.0    NaN      1.0
4   comparison3     NaN      NaN     1.0    NaN      25.0
5   comparison4     NaN      NaN     12.5   NaN      NaN
```

This is the code:

```
for key in dtdc:
    for i, value in enumerate(dtdc[key]):
        n = 1
        t = 100
        if value == t and i > 0 and dtdc[key][i-n] == 1.0:
            dtdc[key][i] = value/2  
            n = n+1
            t = t/2
    break
```

Basically what I did here is I declared 2 variables .The value of n as 1 and t as 100 and then used them in a if loop. I don't know what the problem is. If you could help me resolve the issue , that would be great.

Comment: Will the data always have even number of rows? Also, it's always a good thing to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: No its not necessary. I have a large dataset in csv , I have only posted a portion of that data here.

Comment: Then, what will you compare your last row with?

Comment: Did you write any code to solve it so far? Share with us what do you currently have.

Comment: I made some changes in the question and also attached my approach towards it. Can you guys please take a look?

Comment: I have made some alterations in my question @balderman , please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited: Since your question has now changed, here is the new answer. You can keep track of the index of previous rows as you did, but do it in a while loop and subtract by one each time and divide by half each time the condition is still true.

```
for key in df:
    for i, value in enumerate(df[key]):
        if value == 100.0:
            index = i
            while index > 0 and df[key][index - 1] == 1.0:
                df[key][i] = df[key][i]/2
                index -= 1
```

Comment: I made some changes in the question and I also posted my code @Endyd. Could you please take a look?